# Will someone kill me if I use <br> in JavaDocs?

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

I recently started coding on Java, and I often see single `<p>` tags used to separate lines. But for my purposes, I don't actually want to make 'paragraphs', but just linebreaks, so docs wouldn't be so terrible to read. Are `<br>` tags tolerable?

Finally, I came up with 3 styles of docs suitable for the project. What would I get killed for?

- Looks nice inside the code and bad in doc viewing

  ```
  /**
   * <p> Does highly important adorable things.      </p>
   * <p> Not only helping fields in being suitable
   *     for stack overflowing, but also loves cats. </p>
   * <p> Please do not call while there are
   *     some elephants in the main class.           </p>
   */
  ```
- Looks terrible inside the code and doc viewing

  ```
  /**
   * Does highly important adorable things. <p>
   * Not only helping fields in being suitable
   * for stack overflowing, but also loves cats. <p>
   * Please do not call while there are
   * some elephants in the main class.
   */
  ```
- Looks fine inside the code and doc viewing

  ```
  /**
   * Does highly important adorable things. <br>
   * Not only helping fields in being suitable
   * for stack overflowing, but also loves cats. <br>
   * Please do not call while there are
   * some elephants in the main class.
   */
  ```

Comment: Personally, I would use the result with the best output for interpreters and not code. However, P is a container tag so you 'd want <p>...</p>. For br i would use <br />.

You can make it more code friendly by putting newlines around your tags though.

Comment: `<pre></pre>` anyone?

Comment: Don't you have to ask teammates and users?  Their opinions seem more pertinent than SO.

Comment: (again personally) not too fond of using it for an entire javadoc. java.lang.Long#parseLong has a good use of <pre>

Comment: Prefer <br /> to <br> to have a valid html code (the first one is closed)

Comment: @PieterDeBie Thanks for the advice. I think <pre> could help.

Comment: @JFPicard Thanks. I'm not really in the marking thing.

Comment: I am wondering if perhaps [<ul>](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) and <li> would meet your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a cleaner option is using `<pre></pre>` (which keeps the formatting):

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * Does highly important adorable things.
 * Not only helping fields in being suitable
 * for stack overflowing, but also loves cats.
 * Please do not call while there are
 * some elephants in the main class.
 * </pre>
 */
```